# How to find a random object from a Parse.com collection

Tags: parse-platform

In the absence of Parse.Query.random() I'd ideally like to do:

```
query.count.then(function(theCount){
    return query.skip(randomNumber%theCount).first();
}).then(function(aRandomObjectConformingToQuery){
   // Do stuff to the random object.
});
```

But count operations are discouraged and for large queries won't complete.

Is there any way to get a random object from a subset of a table. e.g. "Get me one of my users who's name is Roger so I can award him a prize" because of the prize, first() doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

So there is no `query.random()` although Parse have added this to their backlog.

In the meantime, there are two ways to get a random object:

1. Maintain a count of your objects and set `query.skip` to be a random number [0,count]
2. Run a query to retrieve all your objects (this may not be possible) and then select a random one from the array.

2 is less error prone because maintaining a count of objects in Parse is unreliable but it isn't truly random. In my case it works though.

Comment: what if I need to query for a number > 1 random objects? Your example ist just for one random object.

Comment: If you want to get n objects from a random index, set the query.limit to be n if you want n random objects, you need to perform the operations I describe n times.

Answer (score 0):

This is working code for fetching random objects from given class in Parse

In cloud code,

```
Parse.Cloud.define("get10Obj",function(request,response)
{ 

query = new Parse.Query(request.params.movie);

Array.prototype.randomElement = function (min, max) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}


query.find ({

success: function(results) {

        var final10 = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            var myRandomElement = results.randomElement(0,results.length);

            if (final10.indexOf(myRandomElement) == -1) {
                final10.push(myRandomElement);
            } else {
                i--;
            }
        }
         var datalist =[];

        for(var j=0;j<final10.length;j++)
        {
            var index= final10[j];
            datalist.push(results[index]);
        }   

        response.success(datalist);
    },
    error: function() {
        response.error(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

In Android,

```
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("movie", "The Matrix");

    ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("averageStars", params, new
       FunctionCallback<ParseObject>() {
      void done(ParseObject ratings, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          // Do your stuff
          }
      }
   });
```